# Как получить название остaновки в Yandex Map android?

Tags: java, android, yandex-maps-api

Как получить название остановки по геоданным в Yandex Map android?

Есть код для определения страны. Как переделать под остановки?

```
private String getCountry() {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            city = returnedAddress.getCountryName().toString();
        } else {
            city = "Error";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        city = "Error";
    }
    return city;
}
```

Comment: Этот код на некоторых устройствах может вернуть вам NPE. И он не является частью Yandex Map Kit. Для того, чтобы определить страну, город, остановку или еще что, советую взять ключ для geocoding Yandex api, и самому сделать запрос, распарсить данные и вытащить все то, что нужно.

Comment: ключ и запрос есть! а вот как распарсить незнаю! уже пол интернета перерыл! не могу найти!!! 
запрос такой: https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=ключ&format=json&geocode=27.604842,53.934570&lang=ru_RU